# how to get the series out of a data frame?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
fake = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
             'State' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
             'Email' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
              }
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(fake)
```

I am trying to define a function that returns a Series of strings of all email addresses of employees in states. The email addresses should be separated by a given delimiter. I think I will use ";".

Arguments:
- DataFrame
- delimiter (;)

Do I have to use for loop?? to be honest, I don't even know how to start on this..

====EDITION

After done with coding, I should run

```
emails = getEmailListByState(fake_df, ", ")
for state in sorted(emails.index):
    print "%15s: %s" % (state, emails[state])
```

and should get something like

```
a: a
b: b
c: c,d
d: e
e: f,g
```

as my output

Comment: have a look at DataFrame [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) and [joining](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) iterables of strings

Comment: BTw , what is your expected out put

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: just providing example output that just shows you in what format the output supposed to be

Comment: I am trying sir. but is there any way I can take two arguments: dataframe, and delimeter(whichever user want emails to be splitted)??

Comment: nah . give me one moment

Comment: def getEmail(sales_df, ", ") ----- so if I put "," then emails will be splitted by comma and ";"  to splitted  by semicolon etc. You know what I mean??

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I think i will work, but I cant check it until I finish the other part of my code. thanks if it has an error, I will get back to you. Thank you Bharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem properly you are looking for groupby state,get the emails and apply join i.e joining the emails based on the state i.e

```
fake = {'EmployeeID' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         'State' : ['NZ','NZ','NY','NY','ST','ST','YK','YK','YK','YK'],
         'Email' : ['ab@h.com','bab@h.com','cab@h.com','dab@h.com','eab@h.com','fab@h.com','gab@h.com','hab@h.com','iab@h.com','jab@h.com']
          }
fake_df = pd.DataFrame(fake)

ndf = fake_df.groupby('State')['Email'].apply(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
State
NY                          cab@h.com, dab@h.com
NZ                           ab@h.com, bab@h.com
ST                          eab@h.com, fab@h.com
YK    gab@h.com, hab@h.com, iab@h.com, jab@h.com
Name: Email, dtype: object
```

If you want that in a method then

```
def getEmailListByState(df,delim):
    return df.groupby('State')['Email'].apply(delim.join)

emails = getEmailListByState(fake_df, ", ")
for state in sorted(emails.index):
    print( "%15s: %s" % (state, emails[state])
```